# Passing a value between classes

Tags: java, bukkit

I need to pass a string from class to another class in Java (Bukkit), I have already read some similar questions, but I can't solve the problem.

I have a Main class

```
    public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {

        new PlayerListener(this);

        this.saveDefaultConfig();

        String bannedBlocksString = this.getConfig().getString("bannedBlocks");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {

    }

}
```

And another class "PlayerListener"

```
    public class PlayerListener implements Listener {

    public PlayerListener(Main plugin) {
        plugin.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, plugin);
    }

    // public static final String bannedBlocksString = "DIAMOND_BLOCK; EMERALD_BLOCK";

    public static final String[] bannedBlocks = bannedBlocksString.split("; ");

    public static boolean isBannedBlock(String[] bannedBlocks, String blockPlaced) {
        boolean returnValue = false;
        for (String bannedBlock : bannedBlocks) {
            if(blockPlaced.equalsIgnoreCase(bannedBlock)){
                returnValue = true;
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onBlockPlace(BlockPlaceEvent event) {

        String blockPlaced = event.getBlockPlaced().getType().toString();

        if(!event.getPlayer().hasPermission("antibuild.block.noplace") && isBannedBlock(bannedBlocks, blockPlaced)) {
            event.setCancelled(true);
            event.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You can not place this block.");
        }

    }

}
```

How can I get the value of bannedBlocksString in Main from the class "PlayerListener"?

Comment: It sounds like you've *tried* something already, but it didn't work - so what did you try, and what happened? (Given that you have a reference to a `Main` instance in the `PlayerListener` constructor, you could have a field in `Main` and a `getBannedBlock()` method or something similar...)

Comment: Thanks everyone, problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I hope it works:

From Main:

```
    PlayerListener pl = new PlayerListener(this);

    this.saveDefaultConfig();

    String [] bannedBlocksString = pl.getBannedBlocks();
```

From PlayerListener you have to declare get method:

```
 public String [] getBannedBlocks(){
 return this.bannedBlocks;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you uncomment the `bannedBlocksString` in the PlayerListener then you can always access it in the Main class using `PlayerListener.bannedBlocksString` as the variable is static.

If you want to do it the other way arround and assign the value you need to remove the `final` from the variable and use the code beneath.

```
    PlayerListener.bannedBlocks = bannedBlocksString.split("; ");
```